# Append in a predefined list in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My DB structure looks like below :

[image]

Now I want to add a new entry under transactionList. For ex :

```
const statement = {
    transactionList : smsFetchedData.transactionList
}
db.doc(`/users/${req.user.userId}`).set({ statement},{ merge: true });
```

Now if `smsFetchedData.transactionList` has 2 entries, it's replacing the whole `transactionList`. What would be the correct scenario to update the same in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append values to a list field, use [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayUnion), as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
db.doc(`/users/${req.user.userId}`).set({
    transactionList: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(smsFetchedData.transactionList)
},
{ merge: true });
```

where `firestore` is your Firestore object import namespace.

Comment: But here `transactionList ` is under `statement`. Shouldn't we need to add that as well ? Although using your approach I am getting the following error :

Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "FieldValueDelegate" (found in field "transactionList"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).

Comment: All I did was replace `statement` with an inline object.  It's no different than what you did, it just eliminated an unnecessary variable.

Comment: I don't know what that error message means.  All I'm doing is what's shown in the documentation.  Feel free to click through to the documentation and read it yourself.

Comment: the values that you add to the array depends on your application, if you want further help, please update you question with that information.